# How to access runtime information in @Advice.OnMethodEnter/Exit ?

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, byte-buddy

I am using **Bytebuddy** to instrument methods.

*Is there any way of getting hold of runtime information as e.g. the thread id of the instrumented method/constructor ?*

I couldn't find a way to gain access to this information using @Advice.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As using visitor is adding the code inside `@Advice.OnMethodEnter` and `@Advice.OnMethodExit`  to the beginning and the end of the method respectively, calling `Thread.currentThread()` inside those annotated methods is resulting in calling the inlined code inside the instrumented method.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getName() / getId()
```